# Git error "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Tags: git

I want to delete my last commit from my project repository. But when i run  'git reset --soft HEAD^ 'or 'git reset --hard HEAD^' ,

it shows 'fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]''

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is simple enough: there is, at this point, only one commit in your repository,<sup>1</sup> so `HEAD~` or `HEAD^`—which names the commit *before* the *current* commit—has no commit to name.  You cannot move the current branch name back one commit as there is no previous commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you have been using `git reset` to move the current branch name backwards, there may be more than one commit in your repository, but you've probably made them all "invisible" and very hard to find at this point.  The reason for this is that Git *finds* commits by starting with a *branch name* and then working *backwards to previous commits*.  The `git reset` command allows you to move the *name* so that it selects any arbitrary commit you choose, but once moved, that name now finds *that* commit and its previous commits.

Pictorially, imagine you have a repository with three commits in it, and just one branch name.  Our three commits have random-looking hash IDs and to avoid using them, we'll just call the three commits `A`, `B`, and `C`; we'll have Git use the branch name `main` to find them:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main (HEAD)
```

Here, the name `main` *points to* (contains the raw hash ID of) the third commit `C`.  Commit `C`—whatever its real hash ID is—contains a snapshot of all files, plus some metadata, and its metadata contains the hash ID of earlier commit `B`.  So Git can use `main` to find `C`, then use `C` to find `B`.  Commit `B`, being a commit, also contains a snapshot and metadata, and `B`'s metadata include the hash ID of the first commit `A`.

If you use `git reset` to *move* the name `main` *backwards* one hop, e.g., `git reset HEAD~`, you get this:

```
     C
    /
A--B   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Commit `C` *still exists*, but without knowing its raw hash ID, you *can't find it*.  The name `main` helps you and Git find commit `B`, and commit `B` points backwards to commit `A`, so you can find both of these commits, but you can no longer *find* commit `C`.

A second `git reset` results in:

```
  B--C
 /
A   <-- main (HEAD)
```

where you and Git can find commit `A`, but can no longer find `B` or `C`, unless you memorized or otherwise saved their hash IDs.  You cannot `git reset HEAD~` any more, though, because `HEAD~` means "the commit before commit `A`" and there is no such commit.

Comment: Thanks, @torek! `git reset HEAD~` worked for me!